Zig leaking memory from dynamically allocated ArrayList entries
I'm new to zig and learning it atm. So I tried to write my own unicode split function (because of reasons, please indulge me). Here it is:
fn split_utf8(allocator: std.mem.Allocator, in: []const u8, delimiter: []const u8) !std.ArrayList([]const u8) {
    var list = std.ArrayList([]const u8).init(allocator);
    try list.append("");
    var utf8 = (try std.unicode.Utf8View.init(in)).iterator();
    while (utf8.nextCodepointSlice()) |codepoint| {
        if (std.mem.eql(u8, codepoint, delimiter)) {
            try list.append("");
            continue;
        }
        const last: []const u8 = list.pop();
        defer allocator.free(last);
        const new: []const u8 = std.mem.concat(allocator, u8, &[_][]const u8{last, codepoint}) catch "Something went really wrong";
        try list.append(new);
    }
    return list;
}

test "Split test" {
    var expected = std.ArrayList([]const u8).init(std.testing.allocator);
    defer expected.deinit();
    try expected.append("F");
    try expected.append("1");
    try expected.append("100");
    try expected.append("click");
    
    const actual = try split_utf8(std.testing.allocator, "F 1 100 click", " ");
    defer actual.deinit();
    
    try testing.expectEqual(expected.items.len, actual.items.len);
    // further testing
}

but I always get the error that the address produced by std.mem.concat is leaked.
I've tried the following things:

defer free new (crashes)
in the test, after the assert, loop over actual and free each element (crashes)
appending dynamically allocated empty strings to init a new "word" (Didn't change anything)

I'm pretty lost. I'd like to know how can I fix the split_utf8 method? Building a list of growing things might be something that might come up in the future.
Thanks!

"splitAny or splitSequence or tokenize ... it returns garbage" - I think you should first figure out what's wrong with your code using these functions before you try to delve into writing something more complicated.

Alright, I figured out what I did wrong; splitAny was the function I was looking for, I must have used it wrongly before.
That still leaves the second question, which is of a completely different nature, namely memory management. I think I'll have to write an arraylist of growing things in the future, do you have any tips there? Also editing the question to better mirror this new question.

You don't free individual strings that you have in the array list.
Do something like this:
const actual = try split_utf8(std.testing.allocator, "F 1 100 click", " ");
defer {
    for (actual.items) |str| {
        std.testing.allocator.free(str);
    }
    actual.deinit();
}

Also:

const new: []const u8 = std.mem.concat(allocator, u8, &[_][]const u8{last, codepoint}) catch "Something went really wrong";

The catch here is completely wrong. Just use try. And add an errdefer statement after this line. Like this:
const new: []const u8 = try std.mem.concat(allocator, u8, &[_][]const u8{last, codepoint});
errdefer allocator.free(new);

I would recommend not using this implementation, as it is very inefficient. There are allocate and free calls for every single character in the input string.
